# Bootstrap for WebApp + Ionic for Mobile. Is it a good combination?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I do not know much about web tech and currently, I am planning my own project implementing web app + hybrid mobile app.

Based on my research, it seems many people use bootstrap, on the other hand for mobile, ionic seems one of the most popular ones.

```
web:    bootstrap +
mobile: ionic
```

While planning it, I met an issue, i.e. how I can combine bootstrap source with ionic and its difficulty, and would it take many steps to modify code and apply for both sides.

So my question is

```
1. is it easy to combine bootstrap to ionic?
2. Is there widely used tool that is integrated for web and mobile application development?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is meant to be a CSS library for creating responsive web, be it webapp or mobile. You can easily create a webapp using AngularJS as you mention, and let its responsiveness be driven by Bootstrap.

Ionic 1 is meant to be a **mobile app** development framework, not mobile web. It has got a lot more than just CSS styles; it creates hybrid native apps for Android, Apple and Windows platforms. Though it does just run fine on mobile screens as a webapp.

Ionic 2 has support for webapps so you can easily write your mobile app that can then be deployed either as a native app or on a web server.

Though on both versions of Ionic, you may choose to use Bootstrap for styling your elements but be aware that this won't replace Ionic's own scss. And it might create some unforeseen issues as you've pointed out.

Comment: So Ionic 1 supports mobile app, and Ionic 2 supports web, then in my case should I combine these two?

Comment: My bad. Ionic 1 supports mobile app primarily. Whereas Ionic 2 is mobile app + the web app support. Though, you must keep in mind that both Ionic 1 and 2 rely on Angular 1 and 2 respectively which are very different from each other

Comment: It sounds like Ionic 1 is inclusive of Ionic2  but since they use different Angular, they must be different. OK. I should do some more research on the difference. :) thx.

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap** is primarily for webapps running in browsers.

**Ionic** is targeted to run the applications in a webview using `cordova`. So, it contains many platform specific stylesheets, properties etc.

```
1. is it easy to combine bootstrap to ionic?
```

There is no point of combining both, as IONIC is providing everything you need from bootstrap. ( Element Stylesheets, Common Functions etc ).

```
2. Is there widely used tool that is integrated for web and mobile application development?
```

Angular JS is going to help here. You can reuse most of the angular code is both have the same functionality.

For IONIC 1 : You need Angular 1 and IONIC 2 is based on Angular 2.

Comment: that helped a lot thx :). sounds like Ionic saves time to quickly implement things.

Comment: @Sean83 ionic provides almost the same things just optimized/ modified for mobile experience with a little different way of implementation.